# Regex to allow one special character with at least 5 digits and maximum 6 digits

Tags: regex

I have created a regex which follows the following parameters:

- Minimum length: 5
- Maximum length: 6
- Needs to have at least 5 digits
- Space and Special characters allowed: #&()_+[]:;',/.\-"*
- No alphabets allowed

The regex I created is :

```
^\d{3}[_\+\[\]\:\;\'\,\/.\-"!@#$%^&*()\s]{0,1}\d{2,3}$
```

This is fulfilling the length requirements and 5 digit requirement, however it is not allowing special characters. I am blocked due to this and unable to find any solution, please help.

Comment: in you regex,the special character in the 4th postion of the string,do you want it in anywhere?

Comment: Should it always start with 3 digits, like your regex requires?

Comment: there is no such requirement as the special character should be at 4th digit. I am a rookie into regex so i tried what i thought is the best possible solution. Please guide

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with

```
^(?:(?=.{6}$)\d*[-#&()_+[\]:;',\/.\\"*]\d*|\d{5,6})$
```

if your regex-flavor supports look-aheads.

It uses two alternations. The first starts by checking the length, which including a *special character* always must be 6 (to allow for 5 digits), with a positive look-ahead. Then it matches any number of digits, followed by a *special character*, and finally any number of digits.

The other alternative just checks for 5-6 digits.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hG4jK9/4).

Comment: Hi @ClasG, 
what if we have to allow alphabets and not special characters?would there be a workaround in this regex? 
A great help would be appreciated as i am really stuck

Comment: If the same rules should apply, only allowing one alpha in stead of the special - `^(?:(?=.{6}$)\d*[A-Za-z]\d*|\d{5,6})$`. Or depending on language and regex flavor (which **always** should be stated in regex questions ;) `^(?:(?=.{6}$)\d*\p{L}\d*|\d{5,6})$`